# How to stop drawing after completing one polygon or rectangle in DrawingManager on react-google-maps?

Tags: reactjs, react-google-maps

I'll use my code as a reference:

```
export default class DrawingContainer extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    onPolygonComplete: PropTypes.func
  };

  state = {
    drawingMode: 'rectangle'
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <DrawingManager
        drawingMode={this.state.drawingMode}
        onPolygonComplete={polygon => {
          this.setState({
            drawingMode: ''
          }, () => {
            if (this.props.onPolygonComplete) {
              this.props.onPolygonComplete(convertPolygonToPoints(polygon));
            }
          });
        }}
        onRectangleComplete={rectangle => {
          this.setState({
            drawingMode: ''
          }, () => {
            if (this.props.onPolygonComplete) {
              this.props.onPolygonComplete(
                convertBoundsToPoints(rectangle.getBounds())
              );
            }
          });
        }}
        defaultOptions={{
          drawingControl: true,
          drawingControlOptions: {
            position: window.google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
            drawingModes: [
              window.google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON,
              window.google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.RECTANGLE
            ]
          },
          rectangleOptions: polygonOptions,
          polygonOptions
        }}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

So there are two approaches I followed to try to toggle the drawing mode to default drag mode after first drawing.

1. Either I save the current drawing mode(polygon or rectangle) to my own state and pass it to `DrawingManager`. I set my default varialbe in state called `drawingMode` to `'rectangle'`, pass it to the `DrawingManager` and then, in the function `onRectangleComplete`, I set it as an empty string, and it works since the map initially loads with the rectangle mode. But once I click on one of the drawing control, it never stops drawing, even though the variable is being set to an empty string. So I think there's a breach of controlled component here.
2. The second approach I tried was to explicitly try and find the google [DrawingManager](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#DrawingManager) class to use it's `setDrawingMode` function. But I tried using `ref` on drawing manager and then went to it's state, and was able to see it there, but then I read the variable name `DO_NOT_USE_THIS_ELSE_YOU_WILL_BE_FIRED` - I believe the library prevents this approach.

So how do I use the drawing controls along with changing the drawing mode back to the default after I complete my first drawing?

Answer (score 1):

```
  handlePolygonComplete(polygon) {
      console.log(this);
      const paths = polygon.getPath().getArray();
      if (paths.length < 3) {
           polygon.setPaths([]);
           alert("You need to enter at least 3 points.")
      } else {
          const coords = paths.map((a) => [a.lat(), a.lng()]);
          this.setDrawingMode(null);
          this.setOptions({ drawingControlOptions: { drawingModes: [] } });
          window.addPolygonToState(coords);
  }
```

and

```
 <DrawingManager
      onPolygonComplete={this.handlePolygonComplete}
 >
```

Here I check if the user put at least 3 points, if he/she did, get its coordinates, and remove the drawing mode.

Answer (score 0):

So I just set a toggle with a function that stopped rendering the DrawingManager

```
<GoogleMap
    defaultZoom={10}
    defaultCenter={new google.maps.LatLng(38.9072, -77.0369)}
  >
    {this.props.creatingPolygon && <DrawingManager
      defaultDrawingMode={google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON}
      defaultOptions={
        {
          drawingControl: this.props.creatingPolygon,
          drawingControlOptions: {
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
            drawingModes: [
              this.props.creatingPolygon && google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON
            ],
          }
        }
      }
      onPolygonComplete={(polygon) => this.createDeliveryZone(polygon)}
    />}
  </GoogleMap>
```

Comment: In the above case, if we want to change the radius or size of polygon or rectangle, how will you get that? because component is unmounted, can't use `onPolygonComplete` method